# ICommand not always firing when tab selected

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvm-light

I have a simple ActionBar with 3 tabs attached. When a tab is clicked, the fragment is inflated and the view shows. The tab being click event is fired using an event. Initially, the first fragment is inflated, but the others respond and inflate if clicked.

If I change the event being fired to an `ICommand`, only the last fragment is inflated and then if I click on the first tab, that and the last are inflated. Never the second.

My code is this

```
    ICommand TabClicked
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(() =>
            {
                tab.TabSelected += (object sender, ActionBar.TabEventArgs e) => TabOnTabSelected(sender, e);
            });
        }
    }

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        ActionBar.NavigationMode = ActionBarNavigationMode.Tabs;

        fragments.Add(new TODFragment());
        fragments.Add(new ConditionsFragment());
        fragments.Add(new ResultsFragment());

        AddTabToActionBar("Time", Resource.Drawable.crucifix_colour);
        AddTabToActionBar("Conditions", Resource.Drawable.weather_colour);
        AddTabToActionBar("Results", Resource.Drawable.tod_colour);
    }

    void AddTabToActionBar(string text, int iconResourceId)
    {
        tab = ActionBar.NewTab().SetTag(text).SetText(text).SetIcon(iconResourceId);

        /* uncomment and comment out one of the two below to see the difference in operation */

        tab.TabSelected += TabOnTabSelected;
        //tab.SetCommand<ActionBar.TabEventArgs>("TabSelected", TabClicked);
        ActionBar.AddTab(tab);
    }

    void TabOnTabSelected(object sender, ActionBar.TabEventArgs tabEventArgs)
    {
        var tabNo = sender as ActionBar.Tab;
        var frag = fragments[tabNo.Position];
        tabEventArgs.FragmentTransaction.Replace(Resource.Id.frameLayout1, frag);
    }
```

Am I missing something fundamental here in the difference between ICommands and Events or is it something else?

I'm using Xam.Android and MVVMLight

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. When I create the partial class I define the UI objects like this (or something like this at least)

```
EditText myEditText;
EditText MyEditText = myEditText ?? (view.FindViewById<EditText>(Resources.Id.myEdit);
```

This is fine, but it does mean that once defined, it doesn't get redefined.

Not a problem if the UI is not really going to change, but every time an action tab is pressed, the fragment is refreshed. Only problem is the Id isn't changing as myEditText is not null.

The answer is add a method in the UI definition code that nulls the objects then in the main code, when the UI disappears, call the nulling method. Everything works then